# TypeError: Cannot read property 'body1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my react component using jest and enzyme and while using the mount property I am getting an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'body1' of undefined.** .

**myComp.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//some imports
const myComp = ({ data }) => {
  //state and func.
  const myRender = () => <someCompoenent />;
  return (
    <myList
      activeMenuItemId={activeMenuItemId}
      myRender={myRender}
      id="toggle-button"
    >
      {data}
    </myList>
  );
};
export { myComp };
```

**myComp.test.js**

```
describe("Click tests", () => {
      it("click", () => {
        const clickMock = jest.fn();
        const wrapper = mount(<myComp />);
        const btn = wrapper.find(`[id='toggle-button']`);
        if (btn) btn.simulate("click");
        expect(clickMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      });
    });
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body1' of undefined

      28 |       it("testing login click", () => {
      29 |         const clickMock = jest.fn();
    > 30 |         const wrapper = mount(<myComp />);
         |                         ^
      at typographyBody1 (node_modules/node_modules/core/dist/cjs/helpers/typography.js:1:3994)
```

using react 17.
**Dependencies**

```
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
```

Comment: Could you please include the component that you are testing ?

Comment: Did you change test names between copy/pasting snippets? The test flagged in the error doesn't match the first snippet.

Comment: @DrewReese no I didn't.

Comment: @SarunUK Added component but modified.

Comment: So I guess somewhere in `myComp`'s DOMTree is a component accessing a `body1` property of some undefined object. Can you include that component that is throwing the error?